# Mysql connection error for Spring framework (org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; )

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, jdbc

When I run the main class then this error pop up. I have checked most of the links for this issue but couldn't solve the problem. Please check the following files to get some idea about the problem Thanks in advance.

```
    # bean.xml #
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


                <context:property-placeholder
                    location="com/springproject/test/springtest01/props jdbc.properties" />

                <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
                    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"></property>
                    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
                    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
                    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
                </bean>
                <context:component-scan
                    base-package="com.springproject.test.springtest01">
                </context:component-scan>
            </beans>


          #pom.xml#
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"                                                                                                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.springproject.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>springtest01</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>springtest01</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>


    #NoticesDao#
    package com.springproject.test.springtest01;

    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component("noticeDao")
    public class NoticesDAO {

        private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

        @Autowired
        public void setDataSource(DataSource jdbc) {
            this.jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(jdbc);
        }

        public List<Notice> getNotices() {

            return jdbc.query("select * form notices", new RowMapper<Notice>() {                                                     

                public Notice mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                     Notice notice = new Notice();

                     notice.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                     notice.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                     notice.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                     notice.setText(rs.getString("text"));
                     return notice;
                }

            });
        }
    }

    #jdbc.properties#
    jdbc.username = root
    jdbc.password = 123456
    jdbc.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtutorial

   #Main#

    public class App 
    {
        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            try{
                ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/springproject/test/springtest01/beans/beans.xml");

                NoticesDAO noticesDAO = (NoticesDAO) context.getBean("noticeDao");

                List<Notice> notices = noticesDAO.getNotices();
                for(Notice notice: notices){
                    System.out.println(notice);
                }

                ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)context).close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("==========="+e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your SQL request is invalid, it should be `select * FROM notices` not `FORM`.

Second, I didn't manage to get the same error as you. In fact, I could not even make the application context to find the bean.xml and jdbc.properties files with your current configuration. I changed some configuration as follows:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
```

and

```
<context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties" />
```

put the files in a main/resources directory, then built and successfully ran the project with

```
mvn clean compile
mvn mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.springproject.test.springtest01.App"
```